# VB.NET Form in class is not destroyed when class is destroyed

Tags: vb.net, forms, class

I have created an application.

The main form is "Form1".

I have declared a class in Form1 like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _MyClass As Class1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        _MyClass = New Class1

    End Sub
End Class
```

Class1 is declared like this:

```
Public Class Class1

    Private f As Form2

    Public Sub New()

        f = New Form2
        f.Show()

    End Sub
End Class
```

When I click Button1 on the main form, _MyClass1 is created and Form2 is shown.

Now when I click Button1 for the second time, I expect _MyClass1 to destroyed and a new _MyClass1 to be created.

I expect the first Form2 to disappear because _MyClass1 is destroyed.

I think it only exists in _MyClass1, and since _MyClass1 is destroyed, Form2 should also be unloaded.

Instead, I suddenly have two Form2 windows open.

Where did I go wrong in my thinking?

Coming from VB6, I expect a form to be automatically unloaded if its hosting class is terminated. Isn't this so in VB.NET as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you again click on button. It will not Destroy Previous object of class.

 Every time when you click Button A new Instance or Object is created for class1.

Comment: And what happens to the previous _MyClass object then?

Comment: reference is lost to it and it will get cleaned up by the garbage collector

Comment: And what can I do to terminate / unload Form2? I see that Class1.Finalize is only called when I quit my application, even when I say _MyClass = Nothing. Or should I change my application design because my approach is just dirty?

Comment: @attila Reference will not lost in case of form2 because it is not disposed when a new Instance of Class1 is created.

Answer (score 2):

You Can use :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _MyClass As Class1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

         If Not _MyClass Is Nothing Then ' To check if Class is initialized, If so then Close the Class or form
        _MyClass.close()
         End If
        _MyClass = New Class1

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Class1

        Private f As Form2

        Public Sub New()

            f = New Form2
            f.Text = "form2"
            f.Show()

        End Sub
        Public Sub close()
            f.Close()
            Me.Finalize() ' Call Destructor 
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Now Every time You click Button It will Close the Previous one, Dispose it and Create a New Instance of Class1 at button click.

Answer (score 1):

You have a private form inside a private class inside a form.  IDisposable is precisely for class (forms are classes) which create other disposable objects (CA will tell you when you have code that creates stuff that is not disposed of properly as with 2 out 3 of your matryoshka dolls):

```
Public Class Class1
Implements IDisposable

Private f As Form2

Public Sub New()
    f = New Form2
    f.Text = "form2"
    f.Show()
End Sub

Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

' IDisposable
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not Me.disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
            If f IsNot Nothing Then
                f.Close()           ' or f.Dispose
            End If 
        End If
    End If
    Me.disposedValue = True
End Sub

' VS generated code
Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub

End Class
```

one tweak to Form1.Designer.vb (CA will tell you about it):

```
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
            _MyClass.Dispose()             '  dispose of your toys
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The button click:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' depending on what the point is, this will work:
    If _MyClass Is Nothing Then 
        _MyClass = New Class1
    End If

   ' if you really need it start anew:
   ' If _MyClass IsNot Nothing Then 
   '      _MyClass.Dispose
   ' End If 
   ' _MyClass = New Class1


End Sub
```